# Abstract Class and Abstract Method

Tags: java

I'm writing a program where I create an abstract class Bird. In this class there is a method called chirp() which prints out "chirp". I made an 2 additional classes called Goose and Mallard that extend from Bird with overriding chirp methods that print out different sounds: "Honk" & "Quack". If I was to add another class called Crow that extends from Bird how would I write a method chirp that doesn't overriding?

My approach is to make a method chirp with a different method signature. I think did this but its not compiling as I want it.

Additionally, if I were to make the method in Bird abstract what changes would I need to make to the crow class...

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class Bird {

    public void chirp() {
        System.out.println("chirp");
    }

    //if chirp made abstract
    public abstract void chirp();

}

public class Goose extends Bird {

    public void chirp() {
        System.out.println("Honk");
    }

}

public class Mallard extends Bird {

    public void chirp() {
        System.out.println("Quack");
    }

}

public class Crow extends Bird {

String sound;

public void chirp(String x) {
    sound = x;
} 

}

public class Problem10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Demonstration of polymorphism
        Bird goose = new Goose();
        Bird mallard = new Mallard();
        goose.chirp();
        mallard.chirp();


        //Reference Variable
        Bird bird = null;

        //Prompt the user to enter a number that is either 1 or 2
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number either 1 or 2: ");
        int inputInt = scanner.nextInt();
        if (inputInt == 1) {
            bird = new Goose();
        }
        else if (inputInt == 2) {
            bird = new Mallard();
        }
        else if (inputInt == 3) {
            bird = new Crow();
            bird.chirp("Crow");
        }
        bird.chirp();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Crow#chrip(String)` does not override `Bird#chip()`, since `Crow#chirp` added a parameter that does not exist in `Bird#chirp`. You would have to remove the parameter, or rethink your design

Comment: So, what happens when you compile? What is the error message? What don't you understand about it? Which is the type of the variable bird? Given that type, how can the compiler know that there is a method chirp(String) in the object referenced by that variable?

Comment: @Surace:  No, an abstract class doesn't *need* to have an abstract method in it.  Comment out the abstract method in the above example and you'll observe that it compiles *just fine*.

Comment: @JBNizet I just don't understand how to add a non-overriding method that performs the function of chirp for Crow class. Looking at the below answer (first bullet point) it will always compile as chirp if there isn't any override. I made some edits to the program (not sure if I did it right still :/) but that is the result I get.

Comment: You did add another chirp() method that does not override the Bird's chirp() method. Adding such a method is not what makes the compiler complain. What makes it complain (again, you should read, and post, the error), is that you're calling a method chirp(String) on a variable of type Bird, and there is no such method in the class Bird. It only exists in Crow. But your variable is not of type Crow.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh I see. You are right. I removed the bird.chirp("crow") from the main method and the output is "chirp" as I suppose it should be.

Comment: What happens if I make the chirp() method in Bird abstract. Do I need to make the crow class abstract as well for it to compile? When I do that it says it cannot instantiate type Crow

Comment: You would not make `Crow` abstract.

Comment: @LewBloch What should I do than. This is a homework problem so the things they ask are situational. From what I read I either need to make the class crow abstract or write an overriding method for crow. Do I just write an overriding chirp() method?

Comment: Take a look at my answer and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices for the abstractness:

- `Bird` is abstract, but `chirp` is not: this means there's is no such thing as a concrete "Bird". "Bird" is a general concept grouping together like things. The fact that `chirp` is concrete means that all "Birds" will default to saying "chirp" if they don't decide to override it.
- `Bird` is abstract and so is `chirp`: Same as above, except now there is no default "chirp"; anything that is a "Bird" must come up with its own way of chirping.
- `Bird` is not abstract and neither is `chirp`: in this case, now there do exist such things as true concrete "Birds" that are distinct from more derived things like "Crows" and "Ducks". All true "Birds" say "chirp" and more derived kinds of "Birds" will default to saying "chirp" unless they decide to override it.

In all three of these cases, you can *treat* more derived kinds of "Birds" as Birds, even when there aren't true concrete Birds.

When overriding you have various choices as well:

- Don't override: you get the default behaviour as explained above. This is not an option if the method is abstract.
- Shadow: this means the more derived type has a method of the same name as the base type, but it doesn't actually "override" it. In this case, if you treat a Goose as a Goose it will say "honk", but if you treat a Goose as a Bird it will say "chirp". In other words, the method that gets called *depends on the reference you used to call it*. (I'm not 100% sure you can do this in Java, and haven't been able to find an example so far.)
- Override: this means you did actually override the method. Even if you treat a Goose as a Bird, it will still say "honk". This is called polymorphism, because now you can have a list of "Birds", and even though you're treating them as Birds, they will all perform their task in their own unique overridden way.

Comment: You won't have the "shadow" option in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're about 99% there from the code you've written.  Here's why:

**Overloaded methods - methods with the same name but different parameter lists - will not conflict with each other.**

Case in point, if you leave your abstract class with the defined, concrete method of `chirp`, *or* if you had only defined the abstract method, then you only need to add this to your `Crow` class to get it to `chirp` properly:

```
public class Crow extends Bird {

    String sound;

    // Use this to actually refer to Crow's chirp sound defined prior
    public void chirp() {
        System.out.println(sound);
    }

    public void chirp(String x) {
        sound = x;
    }

}
```

You can create an overloaded method just fine, but given that you're extending from an abstract class, you are still responsible for handling the call hierarchy based on what you want to accomplish.  If `Crow` defined its own way to get a sound based on a field in it, then you're responsible for populating that field on that instance of `Crow`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke a method in a `Crow` instance that's referenced by a `Bird` variable,

```
Bird crow = new Crow();
```

you will need to have the method defined in `Bird` and overridden in `Crow`. Variable type (`Bird`) determines at *compile time* what method the variable can reach. Object type (`Crow`) determines at *run time* which possible override will actually run. So if you want `Bird crow` to call `chirp(String)`, such a method must exist in `Bird`.

You could work around that by having the sound set in `Crow` via a constructor, a setter, or an auxiliary method.

```
Bird bird = new Crow("croak");
bird.chirp();
```

or

```
Crow crow = new Crow();
crow.setSound("croak");
Bird bird = crow;
bird.chirp();
```

or

```
public class Crow {
  public void chirp() {
    play(getSound());
  }

  private Sound getSound() {
    Sound sound = // Figure out what sound
    return sound;
  }
}
```

The choice depends on how dynamic the determination of the sound needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution here isn't about inheritance, but rather naming.

Not every `Bird` can `chirp`. For example, a `Crow` might `kaw` and a `Duck` might `quack`.

This should tell you that a `Bird` must not be allowed to `chirp` if you also want a `Duck` to `quack`, or a `Crow` to `kaw`.

Instead, you should think of a `chirp` as a type of `Noise`. All noise-making birds have a noise that they make (otherwise they wouldn't be noise-making birds).

So to codify this, you might have something like

```
public interface Noise {
    void makeNoise();
}

public class Chirp extends Noise {

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println('Chirp!');
    }
}

public class Quack extends Noise {

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println('Quack!');
    }
}
```

Once you have your noises, you have a couple of options for the birds. You could only have a `Bird` class, and what type of noise it takes determines what type of bird it is, like

```
public class Bird {
    private final Noise noise;

    public Bird(Noise noise) {
        // ...
    }

    public final void makeNoise() {
        noise.makeNoise();
    }
}
```

With the client code something like

```
Bird duck = new Bird(new Quack());
Bird robin = new Bird(new Chirp());
```

The other option extends this a little bit by declaring classes that know what type of noise they'll use.

```
public class Duck extends Bird {

    public class Duck() {
        super(new Quack());
    }
}
```

Which is used like

```
Bird duck = new Duck();
```

I would say to prefer the first option, unless you have concepts which can really *really* only be applied to a `Duck`, and the other `Bird`s simply do not have that concept.